# More efficient way to store values?

Tags: java, store

I'm thinking about making a math program. It will ask a random question from a set of questions, and then verify the answer. Here is what I have so far:

```
String[] questions = {"3 * 19", "21 * 9", "7 * 4", "349274 * 0", "16 / 2", "3 + 86", "5 - 9"};
int[] answers =      {57,        189,       28,         0,           8,       89,      -4};
```

(It is not normally spaced like this; I did it just to show which answers went with what question)

Is there a more efficient way of doing this (I'm only interested in storing the data, **not** retrieving it)?

Comment: How are you storing it now? What inefficiencies are you looking at? Disk space? Serialization time? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{     
    put("3 * 19", 57);     
    put("21 * 9", 189);     
    put("7 * 4", 28);     
    put("349274 * 0", 0);
    put("16 / 2", 8);
    put("3 + 86", 89);
    put("5 - 9", -4); 
}};
```

A quick note from @Bruno Reis:

> Just note that this creates an anonymous inner class that inherits from HashMap. Therefore, it has a (non-transient) reference to the instance of the class where it has been created, which might pose problems if you try to serialize the map.

**UPDATE:** Here is how you would retrieve the value of a random question:

```
Random generator = new Random();
Object[] values = map.values().toArray();
int randomAns = values[generator.nextInt(value.length)];
```

Comment: Why can't I upvote this???? And thank you! This looks much more efficient! :D I will accept as soon as i can!

Comment: Just note that this creates an anonymous inner class that inherits from HashMap. Therefore, it has a (non-transient) reference to the instance of the class where it has been created, which might pose problems if you try to serialize the map.

Comment: @Tony: This isn't more efficient. To be honest, your question wasn't very clear, but since you seemed to be asking what is more space-efficient, what you had initially was more so.

Comment: How will you select questions at random from the map?

Comment: @Adamski Tony was only interested in retrieving the values.

Comment: @fireshadow52: Tony states in his question that his program will "ask a random question", implying that the solution needs to support the ability to select a question at random.

Comment: @Bruno Reis Wow and there I was thinking if Java7 had added some quite strange initialization lists. Never even thought on a static initializer in an anonymous class. Now that's creative thinking!

Comment: @Voo it is not a static initializer. Anonymous classes can't have one. This is an instance initializer.

Comment: @Bruno Reis Doh obviously (how would one access a nonstatic member variable in a static initializer?), not my best day it seems ;)

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to create a dedicated class to store both the question and answer, store these in a `List` and use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) to shuffle the questions.

Using `shuffle` offers a far more uniform distribution of questions each time the application runs compared with relying on the order in which `HashMap` stores questions internally (which will most likely be the same for a given JVM implementation).

In addition, encapsulating the question and answer together is better from an OO-point of view IMO.

```
public class Question {
  private final String question;
  private final int answer;

  public Question(String question, int answer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
  }

  public String getQuestion() { return question; }
  public int getAnswer() { return answer; }
}
```

Then populate list of questions, shuffle and iterate:

```
// Use ArrayList as it supports random access for efficient element swapping:
List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

questions.add(new Question("3 * 19", 57));
// etc.

Collections.shuffle(questions);

for (Question qn : questions) {
  System.out.println(qn.getQuestion());
  // Prompt for answer, etc.
}
```